# How to indicate currently selected control in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The Android device I am using does not have any touchscreen. All it has is a touch pad that can generate KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN, etc. However, I am not sure if my Xamarin app is responding to these events. Is there any setting that one can enable to identify current selection among a group of controls.

When I go the device's home screen and use the DPad keys to move around, I see a thin square around the icon that is currently selected. I am hoping there is a similar setting within Xamarin app to turn on this behavior. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `CurrentFocus` of the activity to get the current focused control. But first of all, when control is focused, it will be highlighted, usually we can modify the control's background to a drawable state list resource for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This visual behavior is for a button to indicate that user has navigated to the control.

> When I go the device's home screen and use the DPad keys to move around, I see a thin square around the icon that is currently selected. I am hoping there is a similar setting within Xamarin app to turn on this behavior.

So this thin square can be the designed background for focused state.

I don't know if there is any setting for it, but if you want to do it in code behind to indicate which control is currently focused, as I said at the beginning, you can use `CurrentFocus` of the activity. For example:

```cs
public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.DpadDown || e.KeyCode == Keycode.DpadUp
            || e.KeyCode == Keycode.DpadLeft || e.KeyCode == Keycode.DpadRight)
        {
            var view = this.CurrentFocus;
            view.SetBackgroundDrawable(...);
        }
    }
    return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
}
```

Forget to say, if you want to do it in code behind, don't forget to change the background back to its old state when a new control is focused. Emmm, seems the state list resource is the best choice here.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you.