# How to programmatically associate a style to a button in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

In my Xamarin app, I create a button `(Xamarin.Forms.Button)` programmatically. I need this button to show a different background image under normal vs hovered state. I have created a style resource similar to what is described at [How to indicate currently selected control in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471963/how-to-indicate-currently-selected-control-in-xamarin). However, I cannot figure out how to apply this style to the button.

The `Button` class exposes a property called `Image` that is of `FileImageSource` type. The closest API I found to load my style resource is `ImageSource.FromResource` static method. However, this method seems to return `StreamImageSource` instance which is not what we need.

Class `Button` does not seem to provide any `Style` property.

Can you please suggest how I can programmatically associate a style to the button? Regards.

Comment: You may want to check again, Button has a Style property 100%.

Comment: About your image question, if it's an image embedded in your app, just assign to `button.Image` any string, specifically the image file name, i.e., if you have an icon called "alert.png" in your resources folder, you can assign to `button.Image` just `"alert"` and it will work.

Comment: Pedro. There is a lot more work to manage images between hovered and normal state. Styles make it simply convenient. Also, Button does not have a style property. You may be thinking about Android button.

Comment: Peter, please check this image: http://imgur.com/a/5VfLQ. I don't understand why you can't see the style property. And I'm not trying to answer your hovered state question, if that were the case I'd create an answer for your question which I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this request you need custom renderers.

To be able to apply your style f.e.: "myButtonStyle.xml" you have to create a custom renderer for your target platform:

Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (YourExtendedButtonClass), typeof (MyCustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.Droid
{
    public class MyCustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var myButton = this.Control as Android.Widget.Button;
            myButton?.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.myButtonStyle);
        }
    }
}
```